# Problem with text and boolean

Tags: modifiers, text-object

When I apply the boolean modifier modifier the letter E shows the
reverse of what I expected that it would have done. Is there any way to fix it?

[image]

File:
https://pasteall.org/blend/0618b60d8e79429083946bc1c867ecce

Comment: looks like it has do do with the size...if you change the size on the z-axis and make it bigger, it is ok. Maybe you should describe how you used the boolean modifier....or show us the blend file without the applied modifier.

Comment: File: https://pasteall.org/blend/0618b60d8e79429083946bc1c867ecce

Comment: if you use the Fast option instead of Exact, it will work fine, I don't know why it still works better than Exact sometimes

Comment: Thanks for help